# How to avoid constant null checks of getView() in Mortar presenters?

Tags: mortar

I wonder what approach you are using to avoid repeated null checks for getView() in Mortar presenters?

Answer (score 2):

90% of the time it's not necessary because a method is happening in response to something initiated from view-land. In the cases where it *is* necessary, something that happens in response to some kind of asynchronous event…we just cope with it.

```
public void omgTheServerSaid(Some thing) {
  MyView view = getView();
  if (view == null) return;
  view.showIt(thing.it);
}
```

This is the kind of thing that makes me want to write in Kotlin from now on.

```
getView()?.showIt(thing.it);
```